# migrate sales order from site to site

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, migration

Since I have a task which have to migrate a site /au to /asia (I know customer's `store_id`  `website_id` need to be changed), i'm wondering if I need to change the `store_id` in `sales_flat_order` table,

If I don't change the `store_id` of `sales_flat_order` table, what problems will be underlying?

If I change the `store_id` of `sales_flat_order` table, what other data I also need to change/update?

Anyone knows that?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was struggling with the same problem. Actually, I wanted to migrate entire sales order data from my old site to new site. Also with data you need to migrate customers, Right?

For Order Migration I have used a Free Extension. Here is the link- https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html.

With this extension I successfully migrated my whole order data into my old site. If you like this, select this as answer to your question, else post more info.